# Loading a list from API with Angular (ng-repeat), then add some additional information with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, list, contain

I asked this before and didn't get an answer. This time around I'll try to explain better.

So basically, I'm loading a list of Formula 1 constructors from the Ergast API. Because the API does not offer all the information I want, such as constructor foundation years, I have to use jQuery to add them.

The HTML markup is pretty simple. Tag for the dynamic content, and an empty tag for the foundation year.

```
<div id="constructors" ng-repeat="constructor in constructors">
   <img src="img/flags/{{constructor.nationality}}.png" />
   <h2 id="constructor">{{constructor.name}}</h2>
   <h3 id"foundYear"></h3>
</div>
```

I know that the following jQuery would work, if there was only one element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#constructor').is(":contains('McLaren')")) {
    $('#foundYear').append('1963');
  }
});
```

I don't really know how to approach this since I'm still quite new to Javascript. Here's a picture to really understand what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not use ng-if to put in that information inside your repeat?

```
<div id="constructors" ng-repeat="constructor in constructors">
   <img src="img/flags/{{constructor.nationality}}.png" />
   <h2 id="constructor">{{constructor.name}}</h2>
   <h3 ng-if="constructor.name == 'McLaren'" id="foundYear">1963</h3>
</div>
```

Or something similar.

You could also use the name as part of the ID of the H3 and then just access the item directly

```
<...id="foundYear-{{constructtor.name}}"....>
```

jQuery('#foundYear-McLaren').append...

If you have a bunch of years to put in for various items you should really just augment the received data in the controller to add a year field and then use

#### {{constructor.year}}

and it will fill in whichever ones have a year.

Comment: Thank you my friend. I already got it working with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="constructors" ng-repeat="constructor in constructors">
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="img/flags/{{constructor.nationality}}.png" />
<h2 class="constructor-name">{{constructor.name}}</h2>
<h3 class="foundYear"></h3>
</div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#constructor .wrapper').each(function(){
    if($(this).find(.constructor-name).text() === "McLaren"){
        $(this).find('.foundYear').html('1963')
    }
    });
    });
```

Please note - 
1. Inside a loop dont declare static ID.
2. DOnt use append, Instead use .html()